# HTML Element Dynamic Positioning

Tags: javascript, php, html, dom

Im trying to dynamically position html elements based on whether or not certain session variables have been set. My code is as follows:

```
<?php if(!empty($_SESSION['fromARPE'])) : ?>

    <script>
        document.getElementById("provenance").style.top = "80%";
    </script>

    <div style="font-size:30px;">Provenance / <br/> Provient de ARPE : </div>
    <div style="position:absolute;left:40%;font-size:70px;" id="provenance"><?=$_SESSION['fromARPE']?></div>
    <div style="border-bottom:1px solid black; margin-left:35%; width:70%;"></div>';

<?php endif; ?>
```

Can it be done this way? If so, what am i missing?

Thank you

Comment: What is the result of this code? Does anything work at all?

Comment: Wasn't working at all, no. Fixed it with the answer below. Thanks for your time though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is fine, you just have to correct some mistakes, see code below:

```
<?php if(!empty($_SESSION['fromARPE'])) { ?>

    <div style="font-size:30px;">Provenance / <br/> Provient de ARPE : </div>
    <div style="position:absolute;left:40%;font-size:70px;" id="provenance"><?php echo $_SESSION['fromARPE']; ?></div>
    <div style="border-bottom:1px solid black; margin-left:35%; width:70%;"></div>';

    <script>
        document.getElementById("provenance").style.top = "80%";
    </script>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: It would be helpful to point out what the mistakes are. Thanks

Comment: Thanks a bunch dude, that fixed it.

Comment: If you don't mind, could you please explain to me the differences